# How do collapse tabbed content by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have basic jquery tabs that I want to use as a menu, but I want the content to be collapsed by default until a tab is clicked, I cant figure out how to make the tabs collapse by default with the code I have, hope someone can help.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="tabs-container">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
        Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>

</div><!-- container -->
```

and this is the javascript:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab');

        jQuery('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        jQuery('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        jQuery(this).addClass('current');
        jQuery("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set no tab with class `current` initially and then show only `div` with `tab-content` and `current` classes.

```
.tab-content {
    display: none;
}

.tab-content.current {
    display: block;
}
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t8t1cmzm/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post CSS for this example.

But nevertheless I suppose you should remove `current` class from your tabs by default.